# Como retirar o nome do form da url no angular 7?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-7

Quando direciono para um componente no angular, o nome do mesmo fica disponível no endereço da página por exemplo

```
http://localhost/#/form-login
```

Teria alguma forma que o nome do componente ficar oculto?

Comment: voce seta o nome das rotas como quiser.

Comment: entendi, porém queria uma forma de ocultar.

Comment: Voce queria usar rotas mas sem que elas ficassem visiveis na url?? Esse é justamente o proposito de rotas se vc quer algo que so controla o que está sendo mostrado melhor usar outro controle de estado como tabs ou algo assim ai vc tem mais controle.